# MySQL UPDATE in sequence with values from same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to implement a running sum in a table. This is normally done by code, however I need to update existing data. After searching the net I know that MySQL does not allow updates where the value is derived from a subquery from the same table but I have also seen tricks that overcome this restriction. Unfortunately nothing I've seen fits my needs. So here is what the table atable should finally look like:

```
ID  amount    asum
------------------
1    10.00   10.00
2    20.00   30.00
3    -5.00   25.00
4   100.00  125.00
....
```

The `ID` column is autoincrement so these values are in a sequence. The values in `amount` are from the UI and the colunm `asum` needs to be calculated along the sequence of `ID`. Therefore I updated the first row manually and tried something like

```
UPDATE atable t 
SET t.asum = t.amount + (SELECT s.asum FROM atable s WHERE s.ID = t.ID - 1)
WHERE t.ID > 1;
```

Alternatively the column `asum` is the sum of all amounts with `ID` <= current `ID`, so I tried

```
UPDATE atable t
SET t.asum = (SELECT SUM(s.amount) FROM atable s WHERE s.ID <= t.ID);
```

Both statements throw error 1093. Anyone out there who's got a solution for that?

Comment: you can't write to a table that you're simultaneously reading from, which is error 1093.

Comment: Have you tried using a temporary table? (fill it with the contents of atable. And use this temp table for the update)

Comment: There's no reason to store asum; it's derived.

Comment: Sorry, user3741598, from a theoretical point ofd view you are perfectly right. Unfortnatelly this is a real software for a till and a new law in my country requires exactly this - to carry the cumulated sum in each record (so that it becomes more difficult to add/delete a record from the till with all tax implications from that...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
-- query wanted
UPDATE atable t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) param
SET t.asum = (@s := (@s + t.amount));
```

The following is a complete demo.

## SQL:

```
-- data
create table atable(ID int auto_increment primary key, 
    amount decimal(6,2), asum decimal(6,2) default 0.0);
insert into atable(amount) values
(10.00),(20.00),(-5.00),(100.00);
select * from atable;

-- query wanted
UPDATE atable t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) param
SET t.asum = (@s := (@s + t.amount));
```

## Output:

```
mysql> select * from atable;
+----+--------+------+
| ID | amount | asum |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |  10.00 | 0.00 |
|  2 |  20.00 | 0.00 |
|  3 |  -5.00 | 0.00 |
|  4 | 100.00 | 0.00 |
+----+--------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- query wanted
mysql> UPDATE atable t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) param
    -> SET t.asum = (@s := (@s + t.amount));
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> select * from atable;
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | amount | asum   |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |  10.00 |  10.00 |
|  2 |  20.00 |  30.00 |
|  3 |  -5.00 |  25.00 |
|  4 | 100.00 | 125.00 |
+----+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this is great!! It took me 3 days and I haven't found anything that worked. This is simple, elegant and solves my problem. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry Dylan, I still have a question: while the statement worked perfectly in MySQL Workbench, using it in the app code I need to add a `WHERE` clause with a parameter, i.e. `WHERE KassaID = @KassaID`. When I execute the query I get the error `Paramter @s is undefined`. I tried using \@s and @@s but both dont work, even when I denoted KassaID as `?KassaID`. What is the proper syntax to denote `@s` as a variable and not a query parameter?

Comment: does it work in the app code without adding the `where` clause?

Comment: Yes, even without the WHERE clause MySql .NET Connector interprets `@` as the introducer for a paramter, no mather how the real paramters are introduced (in my case I am using a question mark). Unfortunately the table has more value sets which I need to separate by a WHERE clause.

Comment: Maybe it is another issue now. In perspective of sql, it should be fine to contain `@`

Comment: Yes Dylan, you are definitely right. The error comes from MySQL .NET Connector and I have posted the problem already in the Oracle MySQL forum. As soon as I get a reply I will post the solution here as far as there is one. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When I executed the query within a scripting environment (e.g. MySQL Workbench) it worked fine. However, when I tried to run it from within code I received an error because MySQL .NET connector interpreted `@s` as a parameter without a value.

To overcome this problem the program needs to connect to the MySQL DB server having the directive `Allow User Variables = True` within the connect string.